# What is model option for I18n.t

Tags: ruby-on-rails

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6226f8f0662f66c8189f7e628dc42ca59d8f980a/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1932

> `I18n.t(defaults.shift, model: model, default: defaults)`

this rails code call `I18n.t` with `model` option. What is it?

[Rails Internationalization (I18n) API — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) do not say about model option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find here
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/locale/en.yml

It is for default

```
 helpers:
    select:
      # Default value for :prompt => true in FormOptionsHelper
      prompt: "Please select"

    # Default translation keys for submit and button FormHelper
    submit:
      create: 'Create %{model}'
      update: 'Update %{model}'
      submit: 'Save %{model}'
```